# Creating a progress bar column when setting the datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource

I created a `DataGridViewProgressBarColumn` from [MSDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646920/populating-a-datagridview-with-text-and-progressbars)

Works fine when adding manual rows and columns. However working with `databind` it does not display the Cell with progress.

> Removing and adding a new Column in datagrid also did not work. (ColumnAdded event)

```cs
  private void myDgv_ColumnAdded (object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
  {
   var columnName = "HelloProgress"; // assume it is the name of the property
    var columnAdded = e.Column;
    if (columnAdded.DataPropertyName == columnName
     && columnAdded.GetType ()       == typeof (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn))
    {
      var column = new CDataGridViewProgressColumn ();
      column.DataPropertyName = columnName;
      column.Name             = columnName;
      myDgv.Columns.RemoveAt (columnAdded.Index);
      myDgv.Columns.Add (column);
    }
  }
```

The column is there, but the dataSource is not updating only that column cells.

How can I use progressBarColumn with databind datagridView?

Comment: make it during the form load

Comment: I did already. However, same behaviour. I also tried to create all columns manually as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052254/change-cell-type-on-databound-datagridview-to-custom-datagridviewcell-type?rq=2), but since the data comes from databind, the column of the progress is the only one which is not updating.

Comment: Why are you handling `ColumnAdded`? If you built a custom DataGridViewColum, you should find it in the Add Column selector in the DataGridView designer, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49742207/7444103). Or you could add it, specifying the correct `DataPropertyName` before you set the DataSource -- This asuming the implementation is correct, so the `Minimum`, `Maximum` and `Value` are synchronized internally and *compatible* with the source of data

Comment: It was only a test to update the column type. But you correct, it is not the better way.

Comment: if your datasource is a table, add the column to a new table, and  use that as datasource, in formload you can define the style of every column

Comment: the problem was my datasource `HelloProgress` property is `double` and the *msdn* code is `int`. Changing the *msdn* code to *double* now is working fine.